# Obtendo valor da Foreign Key - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

Usando Code First - MVC 4 - EF6 tenho as seguintes Model:

```
[Table("usuario")]
public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    [Column("UsuarioId")]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

[Table("Orcamento")]
public class Orcamento
{
    public int OrcamentoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Usuario")]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

No meu controller, obtenho uma lista de orçamento Paginada.

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        OrcamentoService orcamentos = new OrcamentoService();
        IQueryable<Orcamento> o = orcamentos.ListarTodos().OrderBy(x => x.OrcamentoId);

        int paginaTamanho = 20;
        int paginaNumero = (page ?? 1);

        IPagedList<Orcamento> orcamento = o.ToPagedList(paginaNumero, paginaTamanho);

        return View(orcamento);
    }
```

E em minha View, exibo em um foreach

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Squadra.Price.Models.Orcamento>
...
@foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr> 
                            <td>@item.OrcamentoId</td>
                            <td>@item.Usuario.Nome</td>                                
                        </tr>
                    }
```

Caso o Id do Usuario exista cadastrado, ele exibe sem nenhum problema mas se não existe o ID do usuário, eu recebo o erro "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." e o problema está na navegação '@item.Usuario.Nome'.

Há um jeito de exibir em branco este campo caso ele não ache nenhum ID com esse usuário?

Comment: `UsuarioId` em sua base é `not null`? Se sim, ele nunca deveria trazer Usuário em branco uma vez que não é possível cadastrar orçamento sem usuário.

Answer (score 2):

O seu model está faltando o relacionamento (1 usuário pode possuir 1 ou vários orçamentos) e no código para garantir utilize [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) já visto que seu relacionamento pela pergunta é obrigatório, e o método [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) obriga o carregamento do relacionamento.

***Mudanças***

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[Table("usuario")]
public class Usuario
{
    public Pessoas()
    {
        this.Orcamentos = new HashSet<Orcamentos>();
    }       
    [Key]
    [Column("UsuarioId")]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Orcamento> Orcamentos { get; set; }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[Table("Orcamento")]
public class Orcamento
{
    public int OrcamentoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Usuario")]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    OrcamentoService orcamentos = new OrcamentoService();
    IQueryable<Orcamento> o = orcamentos.ListarTodos()
                                        .Include(inc => inc.Usuario)
                                        .OrderBy(x => x.OrcamentoId);
    int paginaTamanho = 20;
    int paginaNumero = (page ?? 1);
    IPagedList<Orcamento> orcamento = o.ToPagedList(paginaNumero, paginaTamanho);
    return View(orcamento);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Funcionou! O Include obriga a ter a relação, assim a linha da tabela só é exibida se houver relação, então não utilizei ela e adicionei a condição que o @CiganoMorrisonMendez indicou e resolveu 100% meu problema! Obrigado mais uma vez!

Answer (score 1):

Troque:

```
<td>@item.Usuario.Nome</td>
```

Por:

```
<td>@(item.Usuario != null ? item.Usuario.Nome : "")</td>
```

Comment: Uma explicação do porque de fazer isso punha a resposta muito melhor, a meu ver.

Comment: @JorgeB simples porque esse objeto usuário será null caso nenhum usuário esteja associado ao orçamento. Então na hora de exibir uma propriedade deste objeto, é necessário validar se o mesmo está preenchido.

Comment: @JorgeB. Explicar o óbvio?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez nem toda a gente sabe o óbvio, foi só uma sugestão.

Comment: Arrumei meu relacionamento das Model, conforme o @HarryPotter ajudou e utilizei esta condição em minha tabela e funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!